# Does the non-printing characters escape characters still needed for PS1 definition?

Tags: linux, shell, prompt

While modifying the definition of my PS1, I saw that "\[" and "\]" markers should be added to help bash to compute the right display lenght. Many exemples on the web do not use them or even mention them.

I searched for a solution to add them automatically, like with sed, but I didn't find any example.

Are they still needed and is there a recommandation not to use sed to define PS1?

This is what I use at the moment:

```
PS1="$(echo -n "$PS_" | sed -e 's/\\e\[/\\\[\\e\[/g' -e 's/[0-9]m/&\\\]/g')"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `\[` and `\]` still are needed, otherwise you'll run into ugly glitches when the command is wider than your terminal window.

Comment: That's what I have read for the escape chars, but what about the use of sed to define PS1?

Comment: The thing is, not all of them end with a 'm'... If you use the escapes purely for formatting, it's okay - it's your bashrc, do what you want. But it's not a very clean way. Many other users instead make variables like `red='\[\e[31m\]'` and then have `PS1="${red}\u${norm} ..."` Nice and clean.

Comment: Wheel, I also use variables to keep the definition easier to read, but all the .bash_color files I saw defined them without the "\\[\\]". So I am wondering. Thanks for your help.